# extract values between 2 strings

Tags: text-processing, xml

I wanted to extract the values between entitlement

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><HorizonResponse><assignedDevices><assignedDevice><deviceType>EOS</deviceType><assignedProduct><installDate>2019-09-19T00:00:00+02:00</installDate><entitlements>600000001,600000080</entitlements><serviceIDs></serviceIDs>2019-09-19T00:00:00+02:00</installDate><deInstallDate>1753-01-01T00:00:00+01:00</deInstallDate><casIndicator>14</optionQuantity><entitlements>600000300</entitlements><serviceIDs><assignedOption>
      ...
```

Comment: Please put clarifications in the actual question, not in comments. Also, your XML seems to be partial as there are several end-tags missing.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the XML document is well formed (it currently lacks five closing tags), you may use `xmlstarlet` to retrieve the values for all `entitlements` nodes in the document like so:

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//entitlements' -nl file.xml
600000001,600000080
600000300
```

To get the value related to a particular `optionID`:

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//assignedOption[optionID=1000929]/entitlements' -nl file.xml
600000300
```

Answer (score 1):

Lacks the elegance of `xmlstarlet`, but this `perl` approach returns the output you require

```
$ perl -ne 'while(m/<entitlements>(.*?)<\/entitlements>/g){print $1," "}' file.xml
600000001,600000080 600000300
```

`awk` approach

```
$ awk -F\< '{for(a=1;a++<NF;){if($a~/^entitlements>/){print substr($a,14)}}}' file.xml
600000001,600000080
600000300
```

`grep` approach

```
$ grep -o '<entitlements>[0-9,]*' file.xml|grep -o '[0-9,]*'
600000001,600000080
600000300
```